# Retrieving multiple rows from stored procedure using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with the following code, it works fine in sql server. I need to use the returned rows to work with the stacked column chart. I don't know how to receive these rows, though I have tried to do so with code given after the stored procedure code. I would really appreciate if anyone could find out where I am doing something wrong. Thank you :)

Stored Procedure Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[weekly]

@id_beleg int           /* CONTAINS THE ID OF THE MACHINE FOR WHICH THE NUMBER OF  ORDERS IS REQUIRED*/

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @montag DATETIME            
DECLARE @weekend DATETIME

SET @montag = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)          
/* SET @MONTAG VARIABLE TO THE DATE ON MONDAY OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/

SET @weekend = dateadd(day, 6, @montag)                         
/* SET @WEEKEND VARIABLE TO THE DATE ON SUNDAY OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/

/* CONTAINS ALL RECORDS OF one PROCESS FOR THE CURRENT WEEK*/

CREATE TABLE #WeeklySieben
(
 Tag datetime,

 Aufträge_anzahl int,

 Anlage varchar(30)
 );

 INSERT INTO #WeeklySieben (Tag, Aufträge_anzahl, Anlage)
SELECT * 
FROM 
dbo.Sieben 

WHERE 
Tag BETWEEN @montag AND GETDATE()

ORDER BY Tag


DECLARE @tempdate datetime

/* CONTAINS ONLY THE UNIQUE MACHINE NAMES*/

CREATE TABLE #Anlage_Sieben             
(   
Anl varchar(30)
)


/* CONTAINS DATE FOR ALL DAYS OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/


CREATE TABLE #alldays       
(   
days datetime
) 



INSERT INTO #Anlage_Sieben (Anl)

SELECT      KURZTEXT    as Anl

FROM        dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT

WHERE       ID  in (SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT FROM    dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT WHERE ID_PROZESS = 5)    
/* SELECT MACHINE ID WHERE PROCESS IS number 5*/     



WHILE @montag <= @weekend

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #alldays (days)
    SELECT days = @montag
    SET @tempdate= @montag
    SET @montag = dateadd(day, 1,@tempdate) 
END


/* MACHINE NAME * WEEKDAYS DATE*/

CREATE TABLE #weekdays      
(

daydate datetime,

Anlage varchar(30)
)


INSERT INTO #weekdays (daydate, Anlage)
SELECT      d.days as daydate
    , a.Anl as Anlage
FROM        #Anlage_Sieben a
CROSS JOIN  #alldays d



/* SELECT NUMBER OF ORDERS ON A PARTICULAR MACHINE FOR ALL WEEK DAYS*/

Select      case
    when Aufträge_anzahl is null then '0' 
    else Aufträge_anzahl    
    end  
from        #WeeklySieben W right join #weekdays wd on W.Anlage = wd.Anlage and W.Tag = wd.daydate 
where       wd.Anlage in (select KURZTEXT from dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT where ID = @id_beleg  )

END
```

C# Code:

```
try
{
int a;
string sql = "weekly";
SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand c = null;
SqlDataReader r = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//For creating 'raum' number of stacked column bars
for (int i = 0; i < raum; i++)
{
    c = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);                    
    c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    c.Parameters.Add("@raumn", SqlDbType.Int).Value= (int)dblOrders[i];
    r = c.ExecuteReader();
    dp.SelectCommand = c;
    dp.Fill(ds, "Aufträge_anzahl");
    dt = ds.Tables["Aufträge_anzahl"];
    //For adding points to a stacked column bar
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j]);
        Chart1.Series[seriesArray[j]].Points.AddY(a);
    } 

    Chart1.DataBind();
    dtSr.Clear();
}
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

dblorders is the double array which holds the IDs for different machines, raum is the  number of total machines. The code generates no error, but it does not retrieve back the  data in the chart.

dbo.Sieben:

```
Tag                  Aufträge_anzahl    Anlage
19.07.2013 00:00:00  2                  Siebraum 1
20.07.2013 00:00:00  1                  Siebraum 4
20.07.2013 00:00:00  3                  Siebraum 2
21.07.2013 00:00:00  4                  Siebraum 1
22.07.2013 00:00:00  5                  Siebraum 5
```

Tag is the date for the day, Aufträge_anzahl is the number of orders for that date, Anlage is machine

Comment: You say there is no error, do you get any data back? Also, what is the value of `raum`?

Comment: yes there is no error as such, but problem is, i need the result of stored procedure for the stacked column chart, but the code in try after r = c.ExecuteReader(); does not execute, and the value of raum is 5 in this case

Comment: did you try dp.Fill(dt) and skip the view?

Comment: no, i didn't tried it, but whatever I write after r=c.ExecuteReader() statement does not get executed in the try block..

Comment: So you have stepped through the lines with Visual Studio's debugger and it just does nothing when you try to step past the `ExecuteReader` line?

Comment: I tested it by using a label, I tried to update the label text after the r = c.ExecuteReader() statement, it does not update, but when I do so before this statement, it get updated

Comment: I was not able to use your procedure cuz of some missing tabels Sieben. but Your weekly procedure expects @id_beleg as parameter and where are you .Open(); your sql connection? if you provide the tables missing with some data to fill it with i will have another look at your code.

Comment: @Labrinths I updated the question with the Sieben table data above, and'@id_beleg'='@raumn' parameter, and sql connection is opened in the code before try block..

Comment: Thank you to all, I myself got the solution for this problem, the problem here was that I was not giving the sql parameter name same to that I have used in my stored procedure, @Labrinths you was quite near to it :D when you asked where is@id_beleg parameter, Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this line:

```
c.Parameters.Add("@raumn", SqlDbType.Int).Value= (int)dblOrders[i];
```

Should be:

```
c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_beleg",SqlDbType.Int)).Value= (int)dblOrders[1];
```

That is, the sql parameter name should be same as used in the stored procedure, `@id_beleg`

Answer (score 0):

Your command r = c.ExecuteReader() returns a SqlDataReader but you never use it.  Instead you execute the stored procedure again with Fill.  I am not sure if this is the only problem but you don't need the datatable, dataset or adapter.  You can just read through your reader like:

```
while( r.Read() )
{
     var something = r["fieldname"];
}
```

The other thing is that you are casting DataRow to Int32, if you go with DataTable instead of DataReader then you should include a field name like

```
foreach( DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
    var something = row["field"];
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing your SqlParameter with the new keyword.  You should be seeing something in your catch related to this.

Comment: I would try what you suggested, and then let you know. Thank you